# How should I approach solving non-linear equations?

Tags: nonlinear-system

I need help creating a method for a program I'm making. I've worked on this countless hours and I can not seem to figure it out. what I need: A method that returns $x$. My variables ( initialized to a given number ):

```
double initial, initial2, initial3, 
    Kab, coefficient1, coefficient2, coefficient3
```

Equation:

```
kab = ((initial2+coefficient2*X)^coefficient2 *
       (initial3+coefficient3*X)^coefficient3)  / 
      (initial-coefficient1*X)^coefficient1
```

I have tried binary search in order to solve it and that didn't work.

Please be patient with me. I am a high school student and I haven't had much advanced math in order to solve these kinds of problems.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Thus, you want to solve $$(x+a)^n\cdot(x+b)^m=e\cdot(x+c)^p$$ for some given (positive?) parameters $(a,b,c,e,n,m,p)$. In the general case, only numerical methods are available.

Comment: what I need is something similar to what you suggested. But how do I go on solving it ?

Comment: ?? You realize it is next to impossible to know what you mean by this comment?

Answer (score -1):

Knowing nothing about your parameters, except that they are real numbers I would suggest to use
$$
F(x) =\frac{(i_2 + c_2 x)^{c_2}(i_3 + c_3 x)^{c_3}}{(i - c_1 x)^{c_1}} 
$$
and solve numerically for zeros of
$$
f(x) = F(x) - k_{ab}
$$
This is possible e.g. by bisection, or by using Newton-Raphson iteration.

Comment: I can not improve this answer without knowing where it might lack.